# Why my logo and promotion picture of my chrome extension are pixelated?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have just launched a chrome extension and cannot figure out those two points :

1. **Why** on the web chrome store **my logo looks like pixelated** (on my laptop uploaded image was good...), here how it's look like :
   [image]
2. **Why** my **promotional picture** doesn't use promotional **pictures I have uploaded** **but use my icon** :
   [image]

Hope somebody has already tackled this issue !

Here my extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-emoticons/mokaebkcdjejgknjpmdpcphgkoebiodg

Thanks !

Comment: Probably a bug in the web store. I think this icon looks bad in other extensions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to upload the 440 pixels promo img in the dashboard, as this is the one that should be used in your second question